# Any good solution to deliver private HTTP service to public with reverse connection?

Tags: reverse-proxy, http, tunneling, apache-traffic-server

I am looking for a solution to let a private LAN HTTP service accessible from WAN with minimal configuration.

For example, I have more than 1000 deployments of HTTP service across nation running in LAN.  These HTTP service are not available to public at the moment.

Now, the HTTP services would like to serve public request.  Configure port forwarding for these HTTP services is tedious.

One near possible solution I can think of is setup a traffic server (or reverse proxy server) in WAN.  These 1000 HTTP services will find a way to register the traffic server and stay connected all the time via some kind of reverse connection of tunneling .  The traffic server will get request from public and route the request to corresponding HTTP service in backend and response the request to public.

After some research, I learned the reverse proxy Apache Traffic Server or Amazon CloudFront or Azure's CDN service may serve the front end well.

However, the backend HTTP services that could only achieve via some kind of reverse connection or tunneling doesn't support well by the front end traffic server.

Please share some opinions that may helps for this case.  Thank you.

Comment: The problem of port forwarding finds its cause in the usage of limited IPv4 address space and thus the use of RFC 1918 private address ranges and subsequent need of NAT. The solution is IPv6. But that is unlikely to help you on the short term...

Comment: Don't forget, without IPv6 registered IPv4 addresses are getting more scarce as ISPs start using CGN/LSNAT/NAT44 with  RFC 6598 address space

Answer (score 0):

Most instances this is solved with an SSH Tunnel or Reverse proxy, which many appliance vendors will add an `enable remote support` button that establishes an SSH Socket with the home network.  You could also use openvpn, just be cautions of security...communication between nodes, key rotation and so on.

More info on [Reverse SSH tunnels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work)

Private LAN, which I assume you mean unregistered IPs or RFC1918 private address space, is slated for deprication as each device will soon have a public, IPv6 address.

Comment: Private LAN refer to private IP addresses like 192.168.0.0